# build a linked list from broken sequnece

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Suppose we have some sequence like A->B, C->D, B->C, D->E
We have to build a linked list out of it.
Output: A->B->C->D->E

There can be two scenarios. First case, we have all the sequences. Second case, sequence data is coming in as a stream.

Need some help with how to approach to solve this problem.

Comment: The question is not very clear.  Are these numbered packets or something?  How would a stream look like?

Comment: input is list of strings, "A->B", "C->D" etc. In first case I have all the elements in the list, I need to construct a linked list from them. In second scenario, the list is coming as a stream, I don't have all the elements in the list at first, I have to keep constructing the linked list as and when I am getting the next string from the stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would just store the data in a Map, like so:

```
Map<String, String> sequences = new HashMap<>();
String input = "A->B";
String[] parts = input.split("->");  // Split input in two parts

sequences.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
```

This map will eventually look like:

```
A: B
B: C
C: D
D: E
```

And potentially a 2nd independent chain:

```
G: F
H: G
```

Now we need to find where each chain starts.  A chain start can be found in this map by looking for keys that are never used as a value.

This can be done by doing:

```
// make a copy of all keys
Set<String> chainStarters = new HashSet<>(sequences.keySet()); 

// remove all keys that are also used as a value
chainStarters.removeAll(sequences.values());
```

Now `chainStarters` will contain the start of each chain.  In the case I described above, that would be `A` and `H`.

Now all that is left is to look up each value in turn in the `sequences` map starting at the keys in `chainStarters` and make a String out of it.  Something like:

```
String currentKey = startKey;  // 'A' for example
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuider(startKey);

while(sequences.containsKey(currentKey)) {
  currentKey = sequences.get(currentKey);

  sb.append("->").append(currentKey);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```